# SQL syntax error on update in trigger using variable

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, sql-update, syntax-error

I am trying to update a table as a trigger is called and I am getting a syntax error on the update statement.

BODY OF TRIGGER:

```
set @diff = old.amount -new.amount;
UPDATE decks
SET decktotal = decktotal + @diff
WHERE deckname = old.deckname;
```

I will add more information if needed but I imagine this to be a particularity stupid oversight on my part that is easily rectified. Thanks for lookin either way!

EDIT: ERROR 1064 error in syntax at

```
UPDATE decks
SET decktotal = decktotal + @diff
FROM old
WHERE deckname = old.deckname;
```

Comment: `declare @diff money` perhaps?

Comment: Tag dbms, that code is product specific.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name MySQL

Comment: Thanks @jarlh, tagged now!

Comment: @Arvo I'm using MySQL, I don't think I have to declare the variable in mySQL, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the problem you are having is in the where clause
you use:

```
WHERE deckname = old.deckname;
```

the problem with this is table old is not specified in the update. To solve this create a variable and assign it to the deckname in the where clause.
Or after set you need to add the table old.

Solution1:

```
declare @old_name varchar(20);     //Disregard if you don't need to declare
select @old_name = old.deckname;
SET @diff = old.amount -new.amount;
UPDATE decks
SET decktotal = decktotal + @diff
WHERE deckname = @old_name;
```

Solution2:

```
SET @diff = old.amount -new.amount;
UPDATE decks
SET decktotal = decktotal + @diff
FROM old
WHERE deckname = old.deckname;
```

Comment: Hey, what do you mean after set I need to add the table old? Thanks! Also the Soloution2 is what I had started with and yes the error is in the where clause.

Comment: Look at "solution2". When you reference in the where clause "deckname = old.deckname" you need to use "FROM" old because you are referencing that table in you where clause. Or what is the exact error you receive?

Comment: Oh sorry didn't see that, I'll try it now.

Comment: Another way to test is to hardcode deckname in the where clause: WHERE deckname = 'somename';

Comment: Hey tried testing with some name and still got an error. I have added the error to the code above! I hope this helps.

Comment: Try taking off "FROM old" and in the where do this: WHERE deckanme = 'nameyouwant';  Tell me if this works when you hardcode.

Comment: No, it doesn't actually. I'm using MySql. Had originally tagged this sql, in case you hadn't see that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110545/discussion-between-stivan-and-bloopiebloopie).

Comment: Well, since you rejected the edit proposal, at least please add the "SET" before the `@diff`, as the code now doesn't work

Comment: I haven't rejected anything.